# RangeError: offset is out of bounds when trying to render 3d objects in Cypress

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js, cypress

I am using Cypress test runner for end to end testing for an Angular application that uses threeJS to render 3d objects in the scene. Everything works fine until I ask for the 3d scene to be rendered, which is giving the error 'RangeError: offset is out of bounds' and the 3d objects are not rendered. Note, this particular error is only showing up when I am using the chrome browser/Electron for Cypress testing. Otherwise it is being rendered on chrome without Cypress.

[image: Chrome being controlled by Cypress]

Using google chrome without Cypress:

[image: Chrome without Cypress]

I was just wondering what could be the reason for this issue?

I tried debugging using the chrome debugger (no error shown in the console) and everything seems to be working fine. I guess it is exclusively related to Cypress.

Comment: Hey :) Are you the developer, or in control of the threeJS scene? Did you try to specify the viewport width & height to some specific values? Maybe Cypress resizes it and it can't render?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I am a developer and no, I did not specify the viewport width and height.

Comment: As far as I know, wrong scaling, aspect ratio can have impact on webgl/canvas apps. Try to set a specific resolution or specific aspect ratio and let me know if it solves your problem :)

Comment: Hi. I did play around with the viewport quite a bit but it doesn't seem to be solving the issue, thanks though. :(  Although, do let me know if something else comes to your mind.

Comment: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1194#issuecomment-528276591

Can you try to add this? Also, read the whole discussion there to get a better understanding of what is happening.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. As it turned out, the problem happens to be because the Content-Length  response header is eaten away in Cypress. Thanks for your help nonetheless :)